# naming and path of controller plugins

Tags: zend-framework, zend-controller-plugin

I'm confused, I've read everything I found about the topic, but it doesn't work.

I want to build a plugin to use the `preDispatch` Action.

I would like to name it like this:

```
class Mosaik_Controller_Plugin_Acl extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
```

My path and name of the file: `C:\wamp\www\mosaik\application\controllers\plugins\Acl.php`

I tried to register the class in my `application.ini`:

```
resources.frontController.plugins.acl = "Mosaik_Controller_Plugin_Acl"
```

I get some errors:

Fatal error: Class 'Mosaik_Controller_Plugin_Acl' not found in C:\wamp\www\mosaik\library\Zend\Application\Resource\Frontcontroller.php on line 117

My exact question is: For this example, how should be the registering  in my application.ini. Is the name of my plugin class correct or do I have to change it? (Like?) I know it is a basic understanding problem, but nothing helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your confusion is mainly because of autoloading and naming/namespaces. The name of your plugin doesn't match an existing namespace (at least not for a standard ZF setup) and autoloading will not be able to match this against an file. Hence your Class cannot be found.

In a standard ZF1 since at least [Version 1.9 -> see 30.3.2 the Module Resource Autoloader](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.9/en/zend.loader.autoloader-resource.html) we have resource type mapping for plugins and you can create an `application/plugins` folder and add your plugins. Here's what it would look like for you

```
C:\wamp\www\mosaik\application\plugins\Acl.php

// the new class name
class Application_Plugin_Acl extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract

// the new application.ini
resources.frontController.plugins.acl = "Application_Plugin_Acl"
```

Comment: so cool, It works!!! Thanks (I know, but this information was really important for me)